# WordPress загрузка медиафайлов - как сделать название папки для отдельных файлов перманентной

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо загрузить некоторое количество файлов на сайт, однако, при загрузке в папку `wp-uploads`, они еще сохраняются в каталоги по дате и месяцу. Возможно ли сделать в настройках или иным способом так, чтобы каталог, в котором они хранятся, имел постоянное название (файлы будет необходимо часто перезаливать).

Comment: Вы можете перезаливать их впоследствии через ftp в каталог в тот же каталог, где они были созданы, например, `2018/06`. После этого надо запустить перегенрацию миниатюр с помощью плагина Regenerate Thumbnails.

Comment: Спасибо, обошелся без плагина.

Comment: И как вы регенерируете миниатюры без плагина?